# Как добавить "прекомпеляцию" luajit кода

Tags: c++, c, lua, luajit

Хотелось бы спросить, а как реализовать аналог define из языков Си на luajit?
Версия luajit 3beta-2.10 или новее, без разницы.
Алгоритм примерно такой:

1. Файл загружается в формате текста (вроде бы так сначала и происходит
   в luajit)
2. Исходный код файла загружается в память для более точной ловли ошибки с помощью stack trace
3. Все дефайны заменяются на их значения в коде, меняется сам текст кода.
4. Дальше luajit выполняет свои нужные преобразования.

Покажу на примере.

Исходный код:

```
--init.lua
$define MAX_IT 10
$define iterate(v,c,s) for it = v, c, s do
$define exit break
$define TEST

iterate(0,MAX_IT,1)
$ifdef TEST
   if it % 4 == 0 then exit end
$endif
   print("Number: "..it)
end
```

Преобразованный код (без define)

```
--init.lua

for it = 0, 10, 1 do
   if it % 4 == 0 then break end
   print("Number: "..it)
end
```

Вообще можно ли это как-то костыльно сделать?

Comment: А почему в тегах `C` и `C++`?

Comment: потому что исходный код написан на Си и нужно редачить исходный код, чтобы всё это сделать.

Comment: а зачем делать костыльно, если существуют внешние препроцессоры, которые этим и занимаются (заменяют дефайны)?

Comment: чтобы не редактировать исходный код luajit

Comment: внешний препроцессор читает твой файл (stdin) и генерирует новый (stdout)